# Freelancing as math expert halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualaikum
I am a freelancer on math websites by solving math problems. Usually, students upload the question with photos either in book or on laptop screen. Sometimes, the question from screen photos show that they were having a test. But, there's a possibility that they uploaded it after they take that test. So, I am doubt for take this question because I don't know if this is halal or haram. For students who upload the questions from their book, I am doubt too because I have searched about helping students with their homeworks, if we help them to solve their homework (meaning explaining to them how to solve it but then they do it themselves) that's fine and halal, but if we do their homework without any explanation, like being their homework jockey, that's haram. On this websites, there are rules for solving math problems such as starting from explaining the concept, answering step by step with explanations for each step, final results, and discussion. But I still have to solve the problems with the correct answer and finish, and when in the discussion session they always say "ok, I got it" as if they only want the answer, not the explanation. Is it haram or halal if I continue to earn money from there?

Comment: why you ask what you know its answer? If you provide the final answer, it is Haram.  The student should learn the process and reach the answer, not you.  so this is against the goal of studying and schools and universities.